# Best Practice: handlng no network in a ReactNative / Redux App

Tags: react-native, redux

I've built a ReactNative app that uses redux, as well as Wix's react-native-navigation library (HIGHLY recommend btw), and am trying to improve the user experience when network connection is lost - really just a simple alert that lets the user know.

I've got all of my fetch() calls in one api.js lib file, and what I would love to do, is wrap each request with a function that checks for connection before fetching (as opposed to doing some sort of per-component implementation I've seen in other SO suggestions).

I've read a bunch about facebook's NetInfo (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html) API, however there are still open issues on it w/ regards to the simple `NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then((isConnected) => {}` use case (it always returns false, per the issues open).

I've tried something like this inside the fetch function:

```
static get(route, params, header) {

return NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then((isConnected) => {
  if ( isConnected )
  {
      // Run / return your API call
  }
  else
  {
    Alert.alert('No Internet Connection', 'Please connect and retry.',[{text: 'OK'}],{ cancelable: false });

  }
});
```

}

I'm wondering if anyone has either successfully utilized the NetInfo api in this way, or if you've come across a better solution for this (likely) common problem.

Comment: Have you tried [react-native-offline](https://github.com/rauliyohmc/react-native-offline) ?

Comment: @marklar holy crap this looks excellent.  Thank you!